# Confusion with understanding abstraction and encapsulation in OOP

Tags: oop

I was learning JS and came across the term OOP. Then, as I was learning OOP and I found such concepts as abstraction and encapsulation. Moreover, as I was making researching on the difference between them, majority of articles says that both abstraction and encapsulation are concerned with data hiding which confused me very much. However, I made an inference that encapsulation is when we just put variables and functions that operate on them in OBJECT while abstraction is when we use access modifiers to restrict access to properties or functions in an object. Again, encapsulation is when we use capsule like object and put variables and functions in it to achieve organization and reusability. But abstraction is when we restrict access to variables and functions inside object. IS THAT TRUE?

Answer (score 0):

Encapsulation means that you protect your data inside your class (or object) for the outer world and like you say you access the private or protected data via methods (functions) from the same object.

Abstraction is something totally different. Lets take an example.
Imagine that you want to use constraints on your form fields. For example you have a formfield 'email' which may not be empty and must contain an valid email.

So you want to add different kind of constraints to a large number of form fields all over your application.

All constraints must have two methods:

1) a method that tests the formfield data if it is valid

2) a method that delivers an error message if the data is not valid

Now before you write all those different constraint objects you could write one ABSTRACT parent class That includes those two methods but without any code:

(I use PHP)

```
abstract class Constraint
{
    // Force Extending classes to define this methods

    abstract protected function validate(string $data);
    abstract protected function getErrorMessage();
}
```

Above class is abstract and cannot be used (instantiated) by its self. But you can write different constraint classes that inherit the above class:

```
class NotEmptyConstraint extends Constraint
{
    // Mandatory overwritten methods:
    protected function validate(string $data)
    {
        if(strlen($data) > 0 ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    protected function getErrorMessage();
    {
        return 'This is a mandatory field';
    }
}
```

Now all your constraint classes have the two mandatory methods which you can safely use without you need to know which exact constraint your dealing with.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

OOP is dogma.

The author of this website wrote an article on abstraction and why it doesn't work:  https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/

In other words, cell phones and LAN phones are not based on the same hardcoded abstraction of a phone. They are free to be their own classes. Barbara Liskov (SOLID) would argue each are subtypes. I strongly discourage tying your hands by creating such arbitrary hierarchical categorization schemes. This is not how real machines are engineered. Refer to fundamental principles of mechanical design, which dictate simplicity of design, meaning less components when feasible. A separate abstract class is a waste of time and distributes the design itself into two modules.

Encapsulation is the fallacious idea that objects own the data they operate on and, therefore, must control access to it. This notion is disproven by manufacturing's model for collaborative work, which is what my architecture is based on. A screwdriver doesn't own a screw simply because it changes its position. It simply has access to it.

OOP and encapsulation led to the distributed process code model. Objects e-mail work to one another like useless office employees who don't keep e-mail trails. If you've ever gotten e-mail from people asking for help who don't give you any information, then you understand my parody. In manufacturing, steps are documented and never communicate, which creates tremendous benefits. OOP is only enough know-how to write monolithic automated processes, not processes which stop on a dime, reverse, can insert or replace steps on the fly, and try steps again. OOP is a model for distributed manufacturing, whereas manufacturing is a model for organizing everyone who creates some product in the same space.